# Add language support in liferay theme

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, multilingual, liferay-theme

I am creating theme using liferay 6.2. I need to add language support in my theme. For this I try to add language portlet by using

```
$theme.language()
```

in portal_normal.vm. By this portlet is added to theme but it did not work.
Also I tried by

```
     $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("portletSetupShowBorders","false")
     <menu class="nav-horizontal" id="language-navigation">
         <ul>
             <li>$theme.runtime("82", "", $velocityPortletPreferences.toString())</li>
         </ul>
     </menu>
     $velocityPortletPreferences.reset()
```

Also I noticed that language portlet does not work for guest (unauthorized) user. The issue has been logged [here](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-42075).

My requirement is whenever guest user comes to site he can change the language and accordingly Theme/site pages/admin/web content should change to the respective language.

Can anyone suggest a workaround to develop this functionality?

Comment: @crv can you suggest some workaround for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved this by adding

```
             <ul>
                <li><a href="/en"+$theme_display.getURLCurrent() title="UK">UK</a></li>
                <li><a href="/de"+$theme_display.getURLCurrent() title="Germen">Germen</a></li>
              </ul>
```

in portal_normal.vm file. 
For localizing footer, I created the Web content with german translation and add it in footer like this

```
<footer id="footer" role="contentinfo">
```

```
        #set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('portletSetupShowBorders', 'false'))
        #set ($portlet_id = '56')
        #set ($instance_id = "lw8tVGo0NyCB")
        #set ($my_portlet_id = "${portlet_id}_INSTANCE_${instance_id}")
        $theme.runtime($my_portlet_id, "", $velocityPortletPreferences.toString())
        $velocityPortletPreferences.reset() </footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the desired language as part of the URL: E.g. view one page on liferay.com in english: http://www.liferay.com/en/radio. Same page in german (well, the content is non-localized, but the navigation elements are): http://www.liferay.com/de/radio. This works also if you have more narrow definitions, e.g. with en_GB for british english.

Answer (score 1):

In addendum to Olaf solution, you can add javascript snippet to the theme, something like this

```
var deutsch = "<a href='/de" + Liferay.currentURL + "'>De</a>";
var spain = "<a href='/es" + Liferay.currentURL + "'>Es</a>";
languagesDiv.html(deutsch + spain);
```

Comment: Thanks Mark and Olaf it worked. How can I change the contents in the theme according to language I select. Do I need to write some property file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Below code work for me in liferay 6.2 community edition. I change then it in configuration show dropdown and added require language from settings.

```
<div >
$velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("portletSetupShowBorders", "false")
$velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("languageIds", "pt_BR,en_US")
$velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("displayStyle", "1")
$theme.runtime("82", "", $velocityPortletPreferences.toString())
$velocityPortletPreferences.reset()
</div>
```